# Toeplitz Operator question

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $\chi_1$ be the map on the unit circle defined by $\chi_1(e^{it})=e^{it}$.  Let $T_{\chi_1}$ be the corresponding Toeplitz operator.  Consider the map $T_{\chi_1}^* T_{\chi_1}- T_{\chi_1} T_{\chi_1}^*$ where $T_{\chi_1}^*$ is the adjoint of $T_{\chi_1}$.  The book I am reading says the map  $T_{\chi_1}^* T_{\chi_1}- T_{\chi_1} T_{\chi_1}^*$ is a nonzero rank one.  It is easy to see it is nonzero but I cannot see why it is rank one.

Answer (score 1):

If you move your operators to $\ell^2(\mathbb N)$, your $T_{\chi_1}$ goes to the unilateral shift $S$. So you are looking at $S^*S-SS^*$. Now, as $S$ is an isometry, $S^*S=I$. And $SS^*=I-E_{11}$, where $E_{11}$ is the rank one operator onto the first vector in the canonical basis. So
$$
S^*S-SS^*=I-(I-E_{11})=E_{11},
$$
rank-one.

If you are not happy with this, you can do the computation directly. Let $f=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_ne^{itn}$. Then it is easy to see that $T_{\chi_1}^*T_{\chi_1}f=f$. Also
$$
T_{\chi_1}T_{\chi_1}^*f=T_{\chi_1}P_He^{-it}f=T_{\chi_1}P_H\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_ne^{it(n-1)}=T_{\chi_1}P_H\sum_{n=-1}^\infty c_{n+1} e^{itn}=T_{\chi_1}\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_{n+1} e^{itn}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_{n+1} e^{it(n+1)}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_{n} e^{itn}.
$$
We conclude that
$$
(T_{\chi_1}^*T_{\chi_1}-T_{\chi_1}T_{\chi_1}^*)f=f-\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_{n} e^{itn}=c_0.
$$

Comment: How do you move your operators to l^2(N)

Comment: Let $e_1,e_2,\ldots$ be the canonical basis of $\ell^2(\mathbb N)$. Then $V:e^{int}\mapsto e_n$ maps one orthonormal basis into another one, and thus induces a unitary operator $H^2\mapsto\ell^2(\mathbb N)$.